# System Startup Folders/Methods on UNIX Platforms?

Tags: java, unix, boot, multiplatform, startupscript

I have a Java application that needs to implement installation features of making a JAR launch on startup.

I can do this on Window by entering a REG file into the registry, but how can I do this on UNIX platforms?  Linux and Mac if the methods are different.

Do Linux and Mac have system startup folders?

Remember that I need to do this programmatically not through system preferences or anything like that.

Comment: What do you intend your program to do upon startup?

Comment: @Gabe registers a SystemTray icon and checks to see when the next task is to be run.  It will then sleep for a period of time and check again later for updates.  I'm trying really hard to design it to be low-cost resource wise.  That's hard with Java.  I love Java, but long-running background tasks aren't where it shines.  I wanted to make a C app to do this part... but that would only work on Windows and I can't figure out how to make a tray icon.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the classic way would be through adding a script in the appropriate `/etc/rcN.d/` directory (where N is a number 0-6 representing the 'run level').  I'm not sure whether that's still the recommended way, but it usually is still supported.  This would also work with minor variations for other mainstream Unix variants (Solaris, HP-UX, AIX).

On Mac, you have to work harder.  The files `/etc/rc.common`, `/etc/rc.imaging` and `/etc/rc.netboot` are related, but there are no `/etc/rcN.d` directories.  There's also a script `rc` and another `rc.local`.  Typing `man rc` reveals:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> `rc.local` is now unsupported and has been replaced with launchd(8), which bootstraps itself via the launchctl(1) bootstrap subcommand to read in launchd(8) jobs from the standard locations.
>
> SEE ALSO
>
> ```
> launchd(8), launchctl(1)
> ```

So, you should investigate `launchctl` and `launchd`, particularly `launchctl`.

Comment: Are those (launchctl, launchd, rc.common, ...) files or directories?

Comment: `launchctl` and `launchd` are programs (see `man launchctl` and `man launchd`) - the Launch Daemon and its control program.  `rc.common` etc are files or scripts in `/etc/` on my Mac, which has been upgraded from earlier versions of Mac OS X so it might be a carry-over, but it is probably a file that's there on a clean new Lion install.

Answer (score 0):

On Macs I think its `launchd`, and on linux its `init.d`.  They are config files.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it on ubuntu.

First create a bash script to run the java app, similar to.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar "helloworld.jar"
```

and save it, in this case called 'HELLOWORLD' in /etc/init.d.

Need to make the script executable so need to run

```
chmod +x HELLOWORLD
```

Finally to make it run on start up

```
update-rc.d HELLOWORLD defaults
```